# Wedderburn's little theorem from a superalgebra point of view - reformulation from upper half-plane $H$ instead of $R^2$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, category-theory, plane-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

If in standard algebra

> every finite division ring is a field

from a *superalgebra* point of view what is the correspondent formulation to say that every "super-finite-division-ring" is a superfield ?
In Wedderburn's little theorem say that

> every finite domain is a field is essentially equivalent to saying that the Brauer group of a finite field is trivial.

So if also *[supergroups](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supergroup)* exists what is generalization from a superalgebra point of view of the phrase "*Brauer group of a finite field is trivial*" ?

I change the height of the interval of the point of view (from [Upper half-plane H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_half-plane) instead of $R^2$-Euclidean plane) so I don't start from lower position (from ground to underground = R-plane) to build same theorem

```
ring
division-ring
field
group
```

but from higher position (from sky to ground "storey plan" ***not*** from sky to underground interval) = Upper half-plane $H$.

```
superring
(super)division-ring
superfield
supergroup
```

to find an equivalent theorem
**NOTE:** 
R-plane is classical two-dimensional Euclidean space denoted $R^2$
A "[storey pla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey)n" is any level part of a building but in this case 'bulding' is our *structure*
 Sorry if I use a familiar image to explain a mathematical concept.